# Closing Multiple Windows At Once

Tags: c#

I have a Windows forms app that opens up two other child form windows on a button click. If I click on the red X, I want all of the windows to close except the parent. Here is what I have but when I click on the red X I get an exception that says unable to access disposed object.

This is what I have in my second child form. If the user doesn't select anything from the datagridview in the child window I click the x on that form I want that form and my other child form frmMessage to close and go back to the parent form.

```
void Fields(string from, string sub, bool rep)
        {
            string name = "";
            txtReplyBool.Text = rep.ToString();
            if (rep == true)
            {
               
                foreach (var username in usernames)
                {
                    name = user.Name;
                }
                email = from;
                txtFrom.Text = name + "(" + email + ")";
                txtSubject.Text = subject;


            }
            else
            {
                var sendto = new frmSendTo();
                sendto.ShowDialog();
                if (frmSendTo.email == null && frmSendTo.name == null)
                {
                    this.Close();
                    this.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    email = frmSendTo.email;
                    txtFrom.Text = frmSendTo.name + "(" + email + ")";
                }
```

This is the parent:

```
 private void btnSendNewMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string from = "";
            string subject = "";
            bool reply = false;
            var sendmessage = new frmSendMessages(from, subject, reply);
            sendmessage.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Always helps if you tell us which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: Sorry ```sendmessage.ShowDialog();``` is throwing the exception.

Comment: If `sendmessage.ShowDialog();` is throwing the exception, then we need to see the constructor for `frmSendMessages` and any load\shown events for that form.

Comment: that code is in the parent form above ```private void btnSendNewMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change that last `else` block to:

```
var sendto = new frmSendTo();
sendto.ShowDialog();
if (sendto.email != null && sendto.name != null)
{
    email = sendto.email;
    txtFrom.Text = sendto.name + "(" + email + ")";
}
this.Close();
```

Note that I'm using your locally declared `sendto` variable in all places.  You were previously trying to use the Form name itself.

Comment: That still throws the same exception. What I want is that if the user doesn't select anything from a datagridview and clicks the red x on the top of the window, the program should close the two children windows frmMessage and frmSendTo

Comment: Try again.  Look closely at the changes.

Comment: That gives me an error saying that it cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Comment: You've got a weird setup then, mixing ShowDialog with static members.   Need to see more code to understand what you're doing.

Comment: I fixed my code and realized that I cant mix the two. But I'm still getting the exception from```sendmessage.ShowDialog();``` which is in the parent form